# (VUEJS) Acessar a query do router antes de injetar os services no vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

(VUEJS) É possível acessar as informações que são enviadas por query no router antes de injetar os services de uma aplicação?

Por exemplo:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import init from '@/services/Services';

const baseURL = 'https://api.exemplo.com.br';
let token = router.currentRoute.query.token;

const services = init(baseURL, token);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),
    router,
    provide() {
        return services;
    },
}).$mount('#app');
```

E quando acessar o endereço: `localhost:8080/teste?token=123` ele conseguir capturar o token antes de montar tudo?

Answer (score 2):

Não entendi muito bem o que você deseja fazer, mas segue a documentação do vue https://br.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#beforeMount. Se o beforeMount(logo antes da montagem começar) for a solução para o que você precisa, você pode usar o `this.$route.query` que no qual irá retornar `{token: "123"}`.